# Microsoft Search Server or Microsoft Search Service in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-search-server

I use ASP.NET 4.6.1 in Windows Server 2008 r2 using Indexing Server.

I use **Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Indexing Service**, same Provider *MSIDXS*

Now, I want use Windows Server 2012 r2.

> Indexing Service is no longer supported as of Windows XP and is
>   unavailable for use as of Windows 8. Instead, use Windows Search for
>   client side search and Microsoft Search Server Express for server side
>   search.

How use  using Microsoft Search in ASP.NET?

I'm confused: I use **Windows Search Server** or **Windows Search Service** ?

Which **OLE DB provider** is required ?

How install **Windows Search Server** ?

How install **Windows Search Service** ? (maybe feature in Windows 2012 R2)

> Downloading and installing Windows Search Server does not install the
>   OLE DB provider. Neither does installing the Windows SDK. The provider
>   is installed when the Windows Search Service is installed.
>
> On Win7/8 desktop OS, this is installed be default (I believe). On
>   server Windows Server 2012, you have to enable the feature.

My code using Indexing Server in Windows 2008 R2 + ASP.NET:

```
            // Catalog Name
            string strCatalog = txtNombreCatalogo.Text;
            string strQuery = "";

            strQuery = "Select DocTitle,Filename,Size,PATH,URL";
            strQuery += ", DocAuthor, vpath, Write, Rank, Create, Characterization, DocCategory";
            strQuery += " from Scope()  where FREETEXT('" + txtNombreFichero.Text + "')";

            // txtNombreFichero.Text is the word that you type in the text box to query by using Indexing Service.

            string connstring = "Provider=MSIDXS;Integrated Security .='';Data Source=" + strCatalog;
            //connstring = "Provider=MSIDXS.1;Integrated Security .='';Data Source=" + strCatalog;

            var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();

            var cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);

            var testDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

            cmd.Fill(testDataSet, "SearchResults");
            DataView source = new DataView(testDataSet.Tables[0]);
            dgResultados.DataSource = source;
            dgResultados.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused: I use Windows Search Server or Windows Search Service ?

You use Indexing search(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805985(v=vs.85).aspx).

> Which OLE DB provider is required ?

For use Windows Search Service use "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows'; Data Source=(local);"

> How install Windows Search Server ?

For use Windows Search Server you should download and install Microsoft Search Server(based on sharepoint) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18914.